# Since it's not possible to create Blob container in Azure ARM, then how can I enable Archive using ARM?

Tags: azure

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-resource-manager-namespace-event-hub-enable-archive) I can enable the [Azure Event Hubs Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-archive-overview) feature using an Azure Resource Manager template. The template takes a `blobContainerName` argument:

- "The blob container where you want your event data be archived."

But afaik it's not possible to create a blob container using an ARM template, then how am I supposed to enable the Archive feature on an Event Hub?

The purpose of the ARM template is to provision everything from scratch, not to manually create some of the resources using the portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you said, there is no way to create a blob in Azure ARM Template, so the only logical answer to this question is: supply existing blob at deployment time. One way to do that would be to create a blob with powershell and pass it as a parameter to ARM Deployment.

Comment: @KristofferJälén https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/9306108-let-me-define-preconfigured-blob-containers-table you can vote for this feature here

Comment: Note the new information in the answer posted later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784057/909180

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't possible before to create containers in your storage account, but this has been changed. New functionality has been added to the ARM template for Storage Accounts which enable you to create containers.

To create a storage account with a container called `theNameOfMyContainer`, add this to your `resources` block of the ARM template.

```
{
    "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "kind": "StorageV2",
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
    },
    "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot"
    },
    "resources": [{
        "name": "[concat('default/', 'theNameOfMyContainer')]",
        "type": "blobServices/containers",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01-preview",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "publicAccess": "Blob"
        }
    }]
}
```

To my knowledge, you can use `None`,  `Blob` or `Container` for your `publicAccess`.

It's still not possible to create Queues and Tables, but hopefull this will be added soon.